# vue class binding based on multiple values

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to name a class based on the value i have in campaignstatus value but when i added the or to check for red it breaks and doesnt work

```
:class="{orange : campaignStatus.value ==='ARCHIVED' || campaignStatus.value ==='PAUSED'} || {red : campaignStatus.value ==='BANNED' || campaignStatus.value ==='REMOVED'}"
```

however this work

```
:class="{orange : campaignStatus.value ==='ARCHIVED' || campaignStatus.value ==='PAUSED'}
```

how can i add the or part for the red class?

Answer (score 1):

```
:class="{orange : campaignStatus.value ==='ARCHIVED' || campaignStatus.value ==='PAUSED', red : campaignStatus.value ==='BANNED' || campaignStatus.value ==='REMOVED'}"
```